# Why these two methods give different answers (limits)

Tags: calculus, limits

Good evening to everyone. I have this limit: $$ \lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x $$
If I use the e number the result is: $$ \lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x = \lim _{x\to \infty }e^{xln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)} = e^{\infty } = \infty  $$
If I use the power property: $$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x =\lim _{x\to \infty }2^{-x} = 0 $$ 
I don't understand why. Thanks for any possible answers.

Comment: ln (1/2) < 0 so e to the x times natural log 1/2 tends to 0, not infinity.  Both methods give the same results.

Comment: Thanks. I just found that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Watch out:
$$\ln\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)<0$$
so:
$$e^{\color{red}{-\infty}} = \ldots$$

Comment: Thanks! It was very helpful!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Your error lies here:

$$\ln (\frac{1}{2})<0$$

Comment: Thanks! It was very helpful!

Comment: You're welcome.